# Importing data from excel to mysql database using vba

Tags: mysql, vba

I´m trying to import data into a MySQL Database, i have searched for many examples and solutions but it didn´t working and i have no idea why. Below is my vba code. I am getting runtime error 2147217900(80040e14) saying that you have an error in your sql syntax; chek the manual that corrsponds to your mysqlfor the right syntax to use near '='41282'

```
Sub Getdata()
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim server_name As String
Dim database_name As String
Dim user_id As String
Dim password As String

Dim a As Long ' counter
Dim i As Long, j As Variant, k As Long
Dim sqlstr As String ' SQL to perform various actions
Dim table1 As String, table2 As String
Dim field1 As String, field2 As String
Dim field3 As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

sqlstr = "INSERT INTO" & table1 & "SET" _
& field1 & " = '" & i & "', " _
& field2 & " = '" & j & "', " _
& field3 & " = '" & k & "'"
conn.Execute sqlstr
Next a
End With
skipwrite:
End Sub
```

Comment: Output the `sqlstr` that you created and you will see that you are missing some spaces: `INSERT INTOtempmaxSET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, space out the table name and `SET` command in the concatenated string. Also, add tick marks before and after due to the reserved words used in column names (which by the way should be avoided as best practices):

```
sqlstr = "INSERT INTO " & table1 & " SET " _
            & "`" & field1 & "` = '" & Format(i, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "', " _
            & "`" & field2 & "` = '" & j & "', " _
            & "`" & field3 & "` = '" & k & "';"
```

Also as mentioned by @Lelio, format the date to read properly into a MySQL `Date` column.

Answer (score 0):

Date in Excel are stored as number of days between 1899-12-31 and the actual date. What you are trying to do is to store a number in a field that has a numeric format.

41282 is the number of days. So you should calculate something like:

```
'1899-12-31' + 'i days'
```

to get the date in mysql format (that by default is YYYY-MM-DD). I don't know the exact string manipulation command for VBA to get this but on the MYSQL side this should fix your error